# How to handle manual .swf caching?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flash

I have a .swf in my rails application, located here:

/public/bin/editor/Editor.swf

It works fine, with one flaw, it gets cached often, so when we release a new version we are usually needing to tell the customers to clear their cache when they experience issues. My question is, how could I force the .swf to break cache when I release a new version? Something like:

/public/bin/editor/Editor.swf?timestamp=124158512132

I tried the above, but it did not seem to work. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: How are you loading your swf?

Comment: Using Javascript (specifically SWFObject)

Comment: I mean, show the code loading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using swfobject.js and want the item not be cached you need to add this, to the swf description:

> swfobject.embedSWF( 'index.swf **?'+ new Date().getTime()**...

of course you can change **getTime()** to the format you like.

Comment: This would force the cache to break every time, what I am looking for is a granular way to enforce/break caching.

Comment: as i told you you can put the the format you like.put there not the miliseconds, put there 2011-07-14, so it would change each day, or put there 2011-07 so it would change each month. Or another timestamp which will will change only after some time. `new Date().getTime() / YOUR OWN MILISECONDS`

Comment: Or if you serve the page dynamically, you could use a revision number harvested as part of your build/publish process. Or that process could bake the rev number into your html page, if you don't serve it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Consider employing a versioning nomenclature to your editor.  For example Editor_v1.01.005.swf

Here's a good format

app_major_minor_patch.swf

There are a number of benefits for doing this, and it will also solve your caching issue as well out of coincidence. :)

Comment: this solution is good only when you have a dynamic HTML which will change the swf call name according to the swf name change. otherwise you will be needing to change HTML to.

Comment: Yes, but could certainly be part of the deployment process.  Leaving the implementation build number a mystery for the developers and any third parties is not a good thing.  :)

Comment: This seems like a lot of manual upkeep. For instance, I have Editor.swf which loads modules in. Can it cache at the module level as well?

Comment: SWF files can be cached, regardless if sucked in as a module or the one embedded in the page.  The browser handles the cache of a request.  Its really not that much upkeep considering it is part of your deployment process.  It's not something you have to manage constantly, only when something changes - and having a record of which version you're dealing with is not a bad thing.